# Error Fail to convert to internal representation, when java use getBoolean - JAVA,ORACLE

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have an error pointing out a failure to convert to internal representation, when using `getBoolean` to get data type char[1 char] in oracle , 
when the record is numeric like 0-9, its successfull, but when the record is a character like T , F (True,False) or Y,N (YES, NO) the error is happening. Here is my code.

```
   List<TestList> objects = query
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TestList.class))
                    .setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(count).list();
```

in TestList.Class i have setter/getter for bollean like this :

```
Boolean installment;
public Boolean getInstallment() {
    return installment;
}

public void setInstallment(Boolean installment) {
    this.installment = installment;
}
```

Here is the full log of error:

> ERROR Throwable:84 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
>   2017-09-14 20:10:58 ERROR Throwable:84 -    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBoolean(CharCommonAccessor.java:185)
>   2017-09-14 20:10:58 ERROR Throwable:84 -    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCharAccessor.getBoolean(T4CCharAccessor.java:697)
>   2017-09-14 20:10:58 ERROR Throwable:84 -    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBoolean(OracleResultSetImpl.java:640)
>   2017-09-14 20:10:58 ERROR Throwable:84 -    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBoolean(OracleResultSet.java:390)

Btw I use `Oracle 11.2.0.4.0` , `Java 7`, `Hibernate 4.3.9`

Please help me guys, thx.
Sorry for bad grammar :)

Comment: @MaciejKowalski when i try to trace and debugging, the error happen on setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TestList.class), and i can't see the code inside this function because this is insite the hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for the custom converter:

```
@Converter
public class BooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String>{
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value)) {
            return "1";
        } else {
            return "0";
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        return "1".equals(value);
    }
}
```

Then in your entity:

```
@Convert(converter=BooleanConverter.class)
private Boolean installment;
```

The converter api is from `javax.persistence` package. You have to be using JPA 2.1+.

Comment: Great, glad it id